# Alternate method for proving the below equation

Tags: complex-numbers

If $z=x-i y$ and $z^{\frac{1}{3}}=a+i b$ then show that : $\frac{\left(\frac{x}{a}+\frac{y}{b}\right)}{a^{2}+b^{2}}= -2$ .       My steps were getting relation between x,y and a,b by cubing $z^\frac{1}{3}$ complex number and equating real and imaginary parts and i proved from that, but is there a complex number way to approach the same problem i mean using properties of complex number ? What i can deduce is that $|z| = (a^2 + b^2)^\frac{3}{2}$ but for above numerator term i am not getting

Comment: If you assume $\,x,y,a,b\,$ to be real numbers then you should state so in the question.

Answer (score 1):

I will assume that the equality $z^{1/3}=a+bi$ means that $z$ is a cubic root of $a+bi$. Then $(a+bi)^3=z=x-yi$, which means that$$x=a^3-3ab^2\quad\text{and that}\quad y=-3a^2b+b^3.$$But then\begin{align}\frac{\frac xa+\frac yb}{a^2+b^2}&=\frac{a^2-3b^2-3a^2+b^2}{a^2+b^2}\\&=\frac{-2a^2-2b^2}{a^2+b^2}\\&=-2.\end{align}